# Update multiple rows in SQL Server with different table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables let's say tables **A and B**. Each table has two columns **ID and Name** but the data in column **Name** of table A and B is different, but `ID` are the same, so I want to update column **Name** in table A with values from column **Name** in table **B**. How to achieve this? If any could be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update tbl1 set tbl1.Name = tbl2.Name
from Table1 as tbl1
inner join Table2 as tbl2 on tbl1.Id = tbl2.Id
```

this is what your are looking for

Answer (score 0):

Try with UPDATE using JOIN

```
  UPDATE TableA
  SET TableA.Name= TableB.Name
  FROM TableA INNER JOIN TableB 
  ON TableA.ID= TableB.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can do as join

```
UPDATE table_a
SET table_a.Name = table_b.Name
FROM table_a
INNER JOIN table_b ON table_a.id = table_b.id
```